# python tkinter Listbox bind with items updated

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python GUI made with tkinter and I want to define a callback method to be called when the items in a listbox change:

1. Item added to the listbox
2. Item deleted from the listbox

I think that should be possible with bindings but I am not sure what is the exact binding name.

Comment: The user can't edit a listbox. Bindings are for user actions. Why don't you just add your callback code to whatever code you are using to add and delete from the listbox?

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in events when data is added to or removed from a listbox. However, since it's your code that adds and removes the data, you can generate your own events with `event_generate` whenever you update the listbox.